# When to use models as parameters over url parameters in API C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, api-design

I have a method within a controller that returns a list of objects. The implementation of the controller is not important. The method is called `GetAllTestsByLocationIdAndPollTypeId` and returns a list of 'Test' objects. The GET takes 4 parameters, a `locationId`, `pollTypeId`, `itemsToLoad` and a string to `search` by. I am looking to add more parameters and feel that passing in 6 objects in a url is a bit much. The method signature looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetAllTestsByLocationIdAndPollTypeId(int locationId, int pollTypeId, int itemsToLoad = 8, string search = "")
```

Should I pass in a model that contains the values I am currently using for parameters?

EDIT: I can't do a `[HttpPost]` because `POST` requests do not get cached and therefore can be expensive and in this case, will be expensive.

EDIT: I solved the filters in the query string using optional parameters to reduce the number of things being passed in.

Comment: What do you mean by "model"? You could have used a strongly-typed model class that takes its values from the query parameters.

Comment: Besides, why not use the *route* to provide the parameters? Eg `{pollType}/{LocationId}/tests` would be a very useful route.

Comment: Yeah so a class that is strongly-typed with parameters as properties or fields and pass this in the body of the request

Comment: My personal opinion is to go for post. If you really concerned  about the performance then you can do a tricky way to do the same. Use Stringly(your object) from your client side while calling the api. and inside api just get it as a normal string an de-serialize it

Comment: The best way to convince yourself is to probably look at what is REST https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html - This will help you known when to use URL parameters and when to post data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is totally upto you but yes when parameters increases & have large size Header size can exceed since it is `HttpGet` where data is sent in header as Query string parameters.

You can try `HttpPost` since it sends data in body, also uses class & don't show param values if data is over https:

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GetAllTestsByLocationIdAndPollTypeId([FromBody]TestLocation request)
```

Here I am assuming you, you can create class `TestLocation` or anyname you like with public properties of name of param you need.

Now you need to send `JSON` object of class after `stringify` like `{'locationId':1, 'pollTypeId':1, 'itemsToLoad':10, 'search': 'your text'}` & change ajax to post. Since you have left how you are calling from ajax I leaving that to you

**UPDATE**

---

As per feedback by @PanagiotisKanavos(post is not cached) & information from you that querystring is not long, you can try adding route like:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("MyRoute", "{controller}/{locationId}/{pollTypeId}/{itemsToLoad}/{search}", new { controller = "Region", action = "GetCountries" })
```

or Add attribute at controller level if routes/parameters are unique to action methods:

```
[Route("GetAllTestsByLocationIdAndPollTypeId/{locationId}/{pollTypeId}/{itemsToLoad}/{search}")]
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetAllTestsByLocationIdAndPollTypeId(int locationId, int pollTypeId, int itemsToLoad = 8, string search = "")
```

Now your api call can be like : http://localhost/controller/1/2/10/test

**OR**

You can try of combination of route and query. e.g. {LocationId}/{pollType}/Tests?itemsToLoad=N&search=X as suggested by @KirkLarkin

Comment: While I agree about the number of parameters the other part makes me somehow perplex. URL size limit is pretty high for most use-cases, it's (IMHO) both a poor and misleading design to use POST for what is a GET request (there are other well-established patterns when you really need to pass some big objects, for example when dealing with filters).

Comment: We are using filters. Our API design is not the greatest and our controllers are large. A lot of what our controllers do could be refactored and a model could serve as a way of refactoring and removing all the different combination of parameters

Comment: Using GET instead of POST is a convention violation that isn't even necessary. Query parameters can be mapped to model properties. In fact, they could be mapped to the *route* making the URL a lot cleaner and shorter

Comment: It's not just a convention violation either. `POST` can't be cached, which would make this call very expensive.

Comment: Shall I just use a long query string. It won't be too long and i have control over what I'm passing in

Comment: This is all somewhat subjective, but my advice would be to use a combination of route and query. e.g. `{LocationId}/{pollType}/Tests?itemsToLoad=N&search=X`.

Comment: I like the routing method. I think we are sticking with standard querystrings at this moment but I am going to bring this to the team and use it in future. Thank you very much